# pull items from cognito to dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws

i created a terraform that build http api gateway and connect to cognito. everything work well.
i wanted to pull the user_id + email and watch them on dynamodb, so i created a lambda function that do just that and attached it to cognito as a trigger.

i gave all the necessary permmisions through IAM role, and for some reason nothing is happening.(there are no lambda logs errors)

i tried to create another lambda function with the same permissions and with the same code - and when i attach it manually to cognito - it works!

why is it that when i create the lambda function on terraform and attach to it all it need - nothing happened, and when i attach it manually - it works?

please share your thoughts with me

my dynamodb

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "my_table" {
  name         = "my-table"
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key     = "user_id"

  attribute {
    name = "user_id"
    type = "S"
  }
}
```

my cognito

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "user_pool" {
  name = "user-pool"
  username_configuration {
    case_sensitive = false
  }
  alias_attributes = ["email", "preferred_username"]

  auto_verified_attributes = ["email"]

  password_policy {
    minimum_length                   = 8
    temporary_password_validity_days = 7
  }
  verification_message_template {
    default_email_option = "CONFIRM_WITH_CODE"
    email_subject        = "Account Confirmation"
    email_message        = "Your confirmation code is {####}"
  }
  lambda_config {
    post_authentication = aws_lambda_function.myfunction.arn
  }
  schema {
    attribute_data_type      = "String"
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable                  = true
    name                     = "email"
    required                 = true

    string_attribute_constraints {
      min_length = 1
      max_length = 256
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "client" {
  name = "demo-app-cognito-client"

  user_pool_id                         = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.id
  generate_secret                      = true
  supported_identity_providers         = ["COGNITO"]
  refresh_token_validity               = 90
  allowed_oauth_flows                  = ["code", "implicit"]
  allowed_oauth_scopes                 = ["phone", "email", "openid", "profile", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"]
  allowed_oauth_flows_user_pool_client = true
  prevent_user_existence_errors        = "ENABLED"
  callback_urls                        = ["${aws_apigatewayv2_stage.lambda_stage.invoke_url}/"]
  explicit_auth_flows = [
    "ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH",
    "ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH"
  ]

}
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_domain" "cognito-domain" {
  domain       = var.domain_prefix
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.id
}
```

my IAM

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "cognito_role" {
  name               = "cognito_role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Sid" : "",
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : {
          "Service" : "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action" : "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "cognito_project_policy" {
  name   = "CognitoProjectPolicy"
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action" : [
          "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
          "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
          "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
          "ec2:DescribeInstances",
          "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
          "logs:CreateLogGroup",
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
          "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
          "logs:PutLogEvents",
          "logs:GetLogEvents",
          "logs:FilterLogEvents",
          "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
          "dynamodb:GetItem",
          "dynamodb:PutItem",
          "dynamodb:Query",
          "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}

# IAM Role Policy Attachment for "cognito-role"
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cognito_project_policy_attach" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.cognito_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.cognito_project_policy.arn
}

# IAM Role Policy Attachment AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.cognito_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess"
}

# IAM Role Policy Attachment AmazonCognitoPowerUser
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonCognitoPowerUser" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.cognito_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCognitoPowerUser"
}

# IAM Role Policy Attachment AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.cognito_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities"
}
```

my lambda terraform

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "myfunction" {
  filename         = "myfunction.zip"
  function_name    = "myfunction"
  role             = aws_iam_role.cognito_role.arn
  handler          = "myfunction.lambda_handler"
  runtime          = "python3.10"
  timeout          = 300
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.post_authentication.output_base64sha256

  environment {
    variables = {
      DYNAMODB_TABLE = aws_dynamodb_table.my_table.name
    }
  }
  
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = aws_subnet.private_subnets[*].id
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.sg.id]
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "store_user_to_dynamodb_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCognito"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.myfunction.function_name
  principal     = "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.arn
}
```

my lambda function

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        user_name = event['userName']
        trigger_source = event['triggerSource']
        user_attributes = event['request']['userAttributes']
        email = user_attributes.get('email', '')
        login_time = datetime.now().isoformat()
        status = 'success' if trigger_source == 'PostAuthentication_Authentication' else 'failed'

        table = dynamodb.Table('users')
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'user_id': user_name,
                'email': email,
                'login_time': login_time,
                'status': status
            }
        )

        return event
    except KeyError as e:
        return {
            'errorMessage': str(e),
            'errorType': 'KeyError',
            'requestId': context.aws_request_id}
```

Comment: Lambda function is deployed in a VPC. DynamoDB is an AWS public service. So either create a NAT Gateway which will then allow Lambda to talk to DynamoDB or create a Gateway VPC Endpoint for the Lambda function and add it to the route table of the subnets you are deploying Lambda into.

Comment: thanks for the reply!
unfortunately i tried it(created vpc endpoint) and it's still not working :(

Comment: It's hard to give a definitive answer since there is no knowledge on how your VPC is setup.

Comment: Also, what ports are allowed in the SG assigned to the Lambda function?

Comment: i gave it all trafic from http & ssh